# Convert PCFG to CNF?

Tags: nlp, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I have this rule in a grammar :

```
VP->Verb NP NP   [0.05]
VP->Verb NP PP   [0.1]
```

I want to convert this PCFG(Probabilistic Context Free grammar ) to CNF(Chomsky Normal Form)

To do that I know we can split the rule into two non-terminals

```
VP->@V_N NP
VP->@V_N PP
@V_N->Verb NP
```

Which probability to set for each rule?

Thanks

Comment: The conversion will depend on what you would want the CNF to do and also on the other rules. I assume that you want the resulting CNF probabilities to sum to one. If not, @vsevolod's answer resolves the problem. But he's taking a conditional approach to the probability assignment, i.e. `prob(VP->@V_N NP) = prob(@V_N) * prob(@V_N NP | @V_N)` so the sum of probabilities don't sum to 1

Comment: Well ,I'll use it to fill CKY table .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VP->@V_N NP     [0.05]
VP->@V_N PP     [0.1]
@V_N->Verb NP   [1.0]
```

Because you need to get the same probability for the result by applying both the original and the converted set of rules.

Comment: Thanks Vsevolod -shall we always set this sub prob to 1.0? ..I'm trying to solve CKY problem ,and I got across this case.