# Convert PCFG to CNF: with null production rules

Tags: nlp, context-free-grammar, probability-distribution

There have been similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27649735/2281318) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850826/how-can-i-convert-pcfg-in-cnf-for-this-grammar), but mine is different:

Let's say, I have a probabilistic context-free grammar (PCFG)

```
S --> A [1/2] | B [1/2]
A --> eps [p] | AA [q] | x [r]
B --> y [1]
```

where eps is an empty string, p + q + r = 1 (and q <= 1/2, so that generating process finishes with probability 1).

1. What is Chomsky normal form for this PCFG?

I found it very difficult to get rid of the null production rule `A --> eps` and at the same time keep all the probabilities of generating a given string intact. For example, `a := P(eps) = (1 - sqrt(1 - 4 p q)) / (2 q)` and `P(x) = r / (1 - 2 a q)` (as well as the others) should not be changed after creating a CNF(PCFG).

2. Is there a source for an algorithm that does a conversion PCFG --> CNF(PCFG) for any PCFG? (**or proves this is not possible**)

Searching for this, I found numerous sources, claiming that this is possible, however, I saw no proof for this.
Also, following the procedure for CNF(CFG) (where no probability is assigned to rules) does not work (or at least I do not see how one could generalize this to any PCFG).

---

EDIT: [This pdf](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1460/assets/files/parsing.pdf) (page 112) claims that *It
turns out that every epsilon-free PCFG G has a corresponding binarized
PCFG G′ that generates the same language as G*.

Binarized form of PCFG-s is slightly less restrictive than CFN. Again, the pdf provides no sources / proofs for this claim.

Epsilon free means that there are not rules `X --> eps` (which is not true for the toy grammar above).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is much harder than one might think: [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2374.pdf) contains a 50-page proof of an algorithm that does this.